# How to retrieve values from ontology

Tags: sparql, rdf, jena, owl, semantics

I have  below owl class in my ontology, i want to retrive values in xsd:maxInclusive tags. in another words i want to get value '150' under hasCharacterCount property. How can i achieve this task??. i tried using jena api but i was only able to get class names and property names.

```
<owl:Class rdf:about="http://www.semanticweb.org/ontologies/research/mid-review#Abstract">
    <owl:equivalentClass>
        <owl:Class>
            <owl:unionOf rdf:parseType="Collection">
                <owl:Restriction>
                    <owl:onProperty rdf:resource="http://www.semanticweb.org/ontologies/research/mid-review#hasCharacterCount"/>
                    <owl:someValuesFrom>
                        <rdfs:Datatype>
                            <owl:onDatatype rdf:resource="&xsd;integer"/>
                            <owl:withRestrictions rdf:parseType="Collection">
                                <rdf:Description>
                                    <xsd:maxInclusive rdf:datatype="&xsd;integer">150</xsd:maxInclusive>
                                </rdf:Description>
                            </owl:withRestrictions>
                        </rdfs:Datatype>
                    </owl:someValuesFrom>
                </owl:Restriction>
                <owl:Restriction>
                    <owl:onProperty rdf:resource="http://www.semanticweb.org/ontologies/research/mid-review#hasCharacterCount"/>
                    <owl:someValuesFrom>
                        <rdfs:Datatype>
                            <owl:onDatatype rdf:resource="&xsd;integer"/>
                            <owl:withRestrictions rdf:parseType="Collection">
                                <rdf:Description>
                                    <xsd:maxInclusive rdf:datatype="&xsd;integer">200</xsd:maxInclusive>
                                </rdf:Description>
                            </owl:withRestrictions>
                        </rdfs:Datatype>
                    </owl:someValuesFrom>
                </owl:Restriction>
            </owl:unionOf>
        </owl:Class>
    </owl:equivalentClass>
</owl:Class>
```

Comment: OWL API is the way to for these complex OWL class expressions as this API works on the OWL level. Documentation is here https://github.com/owlcs/owlapi/wiki

Comment: it will be a great help if u can help me to get these values.

Comment: What you've shown is an OWL class axiom `Abstract EquivalentTo ((hasCharacterCount some int[<=150]) or  (hasCharacterCount some int[<=200]))`, so what would be the starting point?

Comment: hi @AKSW thanks for replying. this wont allow be paste whole ontology here, Is there any way i can send it to u?

Comment: Sample output i need:

  class -      www.semanticweb.org/ontologies/research/mid-review#Abstract

 On property -www.semanticweb.org/ontologies/research/mid-review#hasCharacterCount

 Value - 150

On property -www.semanticweb.org/ontologies/research/mid-